# Can't Connect to PostgreSQL with PHP pg_connect()

Tags: php, postgresql, centos

EDIT: I just realized that this question may be better suited to ServerFault. Instead of copying it, a moderator please move it over? Thanks.

I've checked php-info, and the Postgresql extension is there (`pg_connect()` is not undefined). I am also able to connect to postgresql using `psql` on localhost (I've edited my pg_hba.conf file appropriately). Here is the code that's not working:

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
?>
```

This code simply results in "Could not connect: " being displayed in the browser.

I checked my apache log, and here's the relevant error message:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_connect() [<a href='function.pg-connect'>function.pg-connect</a>]: 
Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Permission 
denied\n\tIs the server running on host &quot;localhost&quot; and accepting\n\tTCP/IP 
connections on port 5432?
```

How can I fix/debug this?

Edit: I'm on Centos 5.4 btw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> could not connect to server: Permission denied
>
> Edit: I'm on Centos 5.4 btw.

Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  Chances are that you're hitting a SELinux rule.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I just did `setenforce 0` and it worked.