# Php script not workable through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, postgresql

I have an issue with previously working script and I don't understand what is happening.

To make it simple I have a html dashboard. This dashboard call php script like this

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "script/pgResumeData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
```

It was working perfectly until I migrate the machine. I snapshot my volume then reboot on another machine, everything is working except that the pg_connect of the php is not working !

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=test user=user password=pass") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
```

But if I run my PHP script from the shell "php /.../pgResumeData.php", it's retrieving datas perfectly.

As well the pg_connect return "Query failed:" in the console if I print pg_last_error($dbconn). So seems that I can't get the full error ...

Any idea ?

Edit : Same error if I reach the PHP script with a Browser, but working by shell.

Comment: i don't think you can run javascript from the shell. but i'm not sure. your saying it worked in the past?

Comment: @AryehArmon I meant run the php script from the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It's actually a copy of the following

[Can't Connect to PostgreSQL with PHP pg_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481736/cant-connect-to-postgresql-with-php-pg-connect)

To fix it simply do

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

That's why it was actually working on the shell but not from apache

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
But if I run my PHP script from the shell "php /.../pgResumeData.php", it's retrieving datas perfectly
```

You mean on your new machine right ?

I don't know if postgre work like MySQL but maybe some error with the socket, so it will work since the shell know where the socket is but NOT php ?

Try outputting phpinfo() && php.ini to see if the socket is at the right place.

EDIT: Maybe you'll ask yourself why the hell socket would be a problem since i typed 127.0.0.1, well i had the same problem with my MySQL installation where i couldn't connect with localhost/127.0.0.1 but COULD connect with the shell without any problem and had to use the real ip of the machine to connect, it was just a socket problem. So sorry if i'm wrong :p

EDIT n°2: Seems my answer isn't right since you used php ./yourpath.php it should be the exact same output as if it was run in your browser :/ So ... no idea :'(

Comment: Actually whatever I try to do, from apache (javascript calling the php, or the php itself) my pg_connect return false.

    $dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=test");
    var_dump($dbconn);

    bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

Debug the code:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "script/pgResumeData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false,
      success:function(data) {
        console.log(data) // see the console to see the result
      }
}).responseText;
```

Comment: As i mentioned, the result is "Query failed:" ('Could not connect: ' is use like my copy paste, but I modified to "pg_last_error($dbconn)")