# pg_connect does not return false on failure

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to connect to postgres database using pg_connect in php. If I provide wrong credentials for testing it does not return false.

Instead its return below error

Description:

pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Comment: This is what you are looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253136/how-to-catch-pg-connect-function-error

Comment: Plese check this link if you are using linux or centos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481736/cant-connect-to-postgresql-with-php-pg-connect?wb48617274=7930D0CC

Comment: Thanks Samir, it worked using overriding error handler

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be helpful

```
<?php
function getdb() {
    $db = pg_connect("...") or die('connection failed');
    return $db;
}
?>
```

Comment: tried using above function but still I am getting error.

Comment: I am getting the same error pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Comment: May be version different. follow below link and check your version http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-connect.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to print the result, but printing a value of false prints nothing, so you are just seeing the warning that pg_connect generates.

```
print(false); //prints nothing
```

If you want to see the actual value of a variable, use var_dump() instead:

```
$result = pg_connect(...);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As some one said in comment, you should check here: [how to catch pg_connect() function error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253136/how-to-catch-pg-connect-function-error)

You could hide the error by using @ and do something like this:

```
<?php
$db = @pg_connect("...") or die("failed");
if( $db == "failed"){
  // false
}
else {
  // true
}
?>
```